# What is the diameter of the seat post on Citizen folding bikes?

Tags: seatpost, folding-bicycle

I have searched and cannot find the diameter of the seat post.

I would like to get their Miami or Gotham model, but I know I'll need a seat extension as a 6'2" rider.

Dahon and others make longer seat posts, but I need to know the diameter in order to ensure a fit.

Anyone know the Citizen seat post diameter? Is it 33.9 like the Dahons?

Comment: Also wouldn't mind the diameter of the seat post for "Columba" brands :)

Comment: Which model did you end up getting? Would you recommend it?

Comment: @Arm0geddon My girlfriend and I both got Citizens. Don't remember the model. The height was fine for me, a bit short. They are magnets for theft though. Both were stolen at different times in San Francisco.

Comment: Wow... I'm sorry to hear that! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seat post dimension for Citizen bikes, according to customer support, is 31.8mm.

Comment: Also, I just got the bike today. For any other tall people: the stock size is workable, but pretty short.

Answer (score 0):

Citizen isn't exactly on the forefront of technology, they don't even list an email address on their web site. The specs aren't online anywhere. You're just going to have to call them (800) 682-9579 and have them tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy some digital calipers for $16.  Nice thing to have around the house anyway.

[http://www.amazon.com/Neiko-01407A-Extra-Large-SAE-Metric-Conversion/dp/B000GSLKIW/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GSLKIW)